# Requirements for connecting to DB2 from EF 4.1

Tags: db2, development-environment, entity-framework-4.1

We are trying to test accessing DB2 data from Entity framework 4.1.

Question is what do we need to install on the development machine to get it to work?

Is there any configuration work that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my recent research you need [this software package](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/ad/dotnet.html) but it is for VS2005 and there are possibly additional fees associated with it.